# Help with a Limit

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I have tried to solve this limit with L'Hopital's rule;
$\lim_{x\to0+}(1+x)^{lnx}$ but i applied several times with any result.
I would appreciate if somebody can help me.
Note: Wolfram alpha said that the result is 1, but it doesn't appear the steps to get it.

Comment: I have merged Dr Sonnhard Graubner's answers. If you want to accept his answer, you will need to accept it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint: write $(1+x)^{\ln(x)}$ as $e^{\frac{\ln(1+x)}{\frac{1}{\ln(x)}}}$

Comment: I did it, but i applied L'Hopital's rule several times, and the indeterminate doesn't disappear

Comment: the first step is
$\frac{\frac{1}{1+x}}{\frac{-1}{x\ln(x)^2}}$ and then
$-\frac{x\ln(x)^2}{1+x}$

Comment: And then we get the form 0*infinity, right?

Comment: yes and then we write
$-\frac{\ln(x)^2}{1+\frac{1}{x}}$ and the next step is the last one
$\frac{2\ln(x)\frac{1}{x}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$

Comment: Thank so much! I already get the result.

Comment: it is a very nice example also for the students

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: you should probably move some of the comments into this answer.

Answer (score 1):

To apply l'Hopital's rule, you first need to get the something in the form $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, where $f(x)$ and $g(x)\to 0$ as $x\to a$. In you case, if we let $L=\lim_{x\to0^+}(1+x)\ln x$, then taking $\ln$ of both sides, we get
$$
\ln L = \lim_{x\to 0^+}\ln x\ln (1+x)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\ln (1+x)}{1/\ln x}
$$
Now, you can apply l'Hopital's rule to the last expression, allowing you to find $\ln L$, then raise $e$ to that to find $L$.

Comment: I did that, but i applied the rule like three times, with any result.

Answer (score 1):

Without using Hospital rule also we can evaluate this limit.
Substitute  $x=e^t$ then $x\to0^+$ is same as $t\to -\infty.$ $$\lim_{x\to0^+}(1+x)^{\ln x}=\lim_{t\to-\infty} (1+e^t)^t=\lim_{t\to-\infty} (1+O(e^t))=1.$$

Comment: How did the $t$ (which goes to $-\infty$) disappear from the exponent?

Comment: @robjohn: We can use the binomial theorem.

Comment: With an exponent approaching $-\infty$? That seems hard to do.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $f(x,y)=x^y$ is continuous at $(e,0)$ so
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\left[\left(1+x\right)^{1/x}\right]^{x\log(x)}
&=\left[\lim_{x\to0}\left(1+x\right)^{1/x}\right]^{\lim\limits_{x\to0}x\log(x)}\\
\end{align}
$$
You can also write $x\log(x)=\dfrac{\log(x)}{1/x}$ and use L'Hospital once.

---

**Alternate Approach**
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\log\left(\left(1+x\right)^{\log(x)}\right)
=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(x)}{1/x}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}
\end{align}
$$
Each limit requires one application of L'Hospital.